# Specialization for any vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, sfinae

I'd like to define a function in a template class for different cases of T. My problem is to define the case where T is a vector (whatever it contains).

Here's one of my first attempts :

```
template<typename T>
class Test{
protected:
    T *val;
public:
    Test(T* v):v(val){};
    static string typeName();
};

template<typename T>
string Test<T>::typeName(){
    return "other";
}

template<>
string Test<int>::typeName(){
    return "int";
}

template<typename T>
string Test<vector<T>>::typeName(){
//error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Test<vector<T>>’
    return "vector<" + Test<T>::typeName() + ">";
}
```

I could resolve this error by defining :

```
template<typename T>
class Test<vector<T>>{
    // ... (the same thing)
}
```

but I don't want to do like this, because my class is big, and I don't want to write again the same functions. I would also like to avoid making my class inherit from another, if possible.

By searching here, I read about SFINAE but I'm a beginner with it. I tried every way I could but nothing worked. Here's another attempt :

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,typename E=void>
class Test{
protected:
    T *val;
public:
    Test(T* v);
    static string typeName();
    static void bidon();
};

template<typename T,typename E>
string Test<T,E>::typeName(){
    return "other";
}

template<>
string Test<int>::typeName(){
    return "int";
}

template<typename T> struct IsVector            : public std::false_type{};
template<typename T> struct IsVector<vector<T>> : public std::true_type {};

template<typename T,typename E>
    string Test<T,typename std::enable_if<IsVector<T>::value,E>::type>::typeName(){
    return "vector<" + Test<typename T::value_type>::typeName() + ">";
}
```

I had the same error. What's wrong with it ? Am I trying to do impossible things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want with this. The result is the same even though the approach is a little bit different.

```
template <typename V>
struct typeName {};

// Handle pointers
template <typename V>
struct typeName<V*> {
    static string name;
};
template <typename V>
string typeName<V*>::name = typeName<V>::name + "*";

template <>
struct typeName<string> {
    static string name;
};
string typeName<string>::name = "string";


template <>
struct typeName<int> {
    static string name;
};
string typeName<int>::name = "int";

template <typename V>
struct typeName<vector<V>> {
    static string name;
};

template <typename V>
string typeName<vector<V>>::name = "vector<" + typeName<V>::name + ">";


template <typename V>
struct typeName<set<V>> {
    static string name;
};

template <typename V>
string typeName<set<V>>::name = "set<" + typeName<V>::name + ">";


int main() {
    cout << typeName<vector<string>>::name << endl;   
    cout << typeName<set<string>>::name << endl;   
    cout << typeName<vector<set<string*>*>>::name;   
}
```

---

```
stdout

vector<string>
set<string>
vector<set<string*>*>
```

Comment: @Gilles OK I think this fits your needs. See the edit. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, so this is the "helper class". I like it even more ! This is very clearer for me now, your were all so helpful, you can't imagine the time I spent before to understand, I thought I was going crazy :) Thank you all !

Comment: Oops, I didn't know I hat to accept an answer. Thanks you all. Too bad I can accept only one answer.

Comment: @Gilles ya it is only one answer. I think i got lucky this time :)

Answer (score 3):

Since your `typeName` method is both `static` and `public`, you can use a free helper function like this:

```
template< typename T > struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

template< typename... Ts > struct is_vector<vector<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

// Standard-confirming compilers will accept the above specialization, but
// if your compiler doesn't like the above, you need to manually provide all
// template arguments to detect std::vector properly:

// template< typename T, typename Allocator >
// struct is_vector<vector<T,Allocator>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !is_vector<T>::value, string >::type testTypeName(){
    return "other";
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< is_vector<T>::value, string >::type testTypeName(){
    return "vector<" + Test<typename T::value_type>::typeName() + ">";
}

template<>
string Test<int>::typeName(){
    return "int";
}

template<typename T>
string Test<T>::typeName(){
    return testTypeName<T>();
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks ! I just had a little problem with Ts... in is_vector but it was ok with T. But If my method is not static, Do I have to do the same thing, with string testTypeName(const Test& t) or is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: @Gilles You're welcome. Note that if you need more specializations for `map`, etc. you should use a helper class instead of a helper function, much easier to scale it. If the above is not sufficient and you want to know more about this, let me know and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Gilles If it's not static, one option is what you wrote, passing a parameter of `const Test<T>&` (or `Test<T>&`). But there are many other options which might be preferable, but it's hard to know from a small example. It depends on how many methods you want to specialize, if the specializations are always in sync or not, etc. I'm afraid there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate template, which contains the function, and have the main template call the function of the helper template:

```
template <typename T>
struct tn_helper {
    static string typeName(){
        return "other";
    }
};

template <typename T>
string Test::typeName(){
    return tn_helper<T>::typeName();;
}

template<>
struct tn_helper<int> {
    static string typeName(){
        return "int";
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct tn_helper<vector<T> > {
    static string typeName(){
        return "vector<" + tn_helper<T>::typeName() + ">";
    }
};

// etc.
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I'm not sure to see what you mean in your note : like my first attemp, or as just above. Thank anyway.

Comment: corrected my answer, though it must be quite similar to the accepted one. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your original attempt doesn't work (just like you I'd expect it to compile, let's hope someone else can shed some light on this) but as a workaround you could make a separate template class which contains only your static function, and use that class in your main class. Something along the lines of:

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeName {
    static std::string typeName() { return "other"; }
};
template<>
struct TypeName<int> {
    static std::string typeName() { return "int"; }
};
template<typename T>
struct TypeName<std::vector<T>> {
    static std::string typeName() { return "vector<" + TypeName<T>::typeName() + ">"; }
};

template<typename T>
class Test {
public:
    static std::string typeName() { return TypeName<T>::typeName(); }
    // more stuff
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This would fit even better my case !